# Writing image not working properly using BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java

Iam reading and writing an image file in java.the file can be of any type so i used buffered reader and writer while writing image its not written properly.The image get scattered.

```
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedWriter = null;

        if(!(dto.getInputStream() == null)){

            try {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dto.getInputStream()));
                FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new File(WEBINFLocation.getWebInfPath()+ConstantIFC.RESOURCEPATH+dto.getFileName()+dto.getDocumentCode()+"_"+dto.getVersion()+1+"."+dto.getFormatName()));

                bufferedWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(writer);
                int value;
                while((value = bufferedReader.read()) != -1){
                    bufferedWriter.write(value);                    
                }                   

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bufferedReader != null) {             
                        bufferedReader.close();             
                    }
                    if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                    }

                    dto.getInputStream().close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dto.getInputStream()));
```

You're using an `InputStreamReader`, which means it's reading the *binary* data as *text*. Don't do that. Your `OutputStream` is fine, it's your *input* handling which is broken.

You should just use `InputStream`, or possibly `BufferedInputStream`, ideally reading blocks of data at a time instead of a single byte:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Try to read 8K at a time
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

There are various libraries which help to do this for you, e.g. with [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) you can use [`BytesStreams.copy`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

Also note that if you're just Java 7, your code can be *much* simpler using a try-with-resources statement to perform all the closing for you. For example:

```
try (InputStream input = dto.getInputStream();
     OutputStream output = Files.newOutputStream(...)) {
     BytesStreams.copy(input, output);
}
```

Use the [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) API to specify the path to your file - I'd suggest using a call to `String.format` instead of all that concatenation, too.